# Postgres Unique constraint based column value

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
    id varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    legacy_id varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    short_name varchar(255) NULL,   
    is_deleted bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    CONSTRAINT employee_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I want to plan for unique constraint like this

The table must have these constraint

```
1. Unique constraint is required on column 'legacy_id' and 'is_deleted = false'. Its okay to have multiple values with legacy_id and is_deleted = true.
```

Is there any way to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a constraint for that, but a partial unique index will do just as well:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON employee (legacy_id)
   WHERE is_deleted;
```